# Свой тип данных

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Помогите создать свой тип данных с использованием перегрузки.
Я пытался сделать следующее:

```
class dot
{
    float *a1, *a2;
    dot()
    {
        a1 = new float;
        a2 = new float;
    }
    void operator = (const float *znach)
    {
        *a1 = *znach;
        *a2 = *(znach + 1);
        cout << " a = " << *a1 << " b = " << *a2 << endl;
    }
    ~dot()
    {
        delete a1;
        delete a2;
    }
};
```

Где `dot` - точка пространства. Как мне ввести туда две координаты `x,y`?
Как вообще использовать перегрузки при создании своего типа?
Зачем нужен `typedef`? Как его использовать?

Comment: В первую очередь у вас надо спросить: почему вдруг поля представлены указателями с выделением памяти через `new`?

Comment: @AnT хм, это имеет значение?

Comment: ну так напишите где то такую функцию `void set(float b1, float b2) { *a1 = b1; *a2 = b2; }` и не забудьте сделать функции/конструкторы публичными.

Comment: @KoVadim как это сделать перегрузкой?

Comment: какой перегрузкой? что перегружать собрались?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для такого простого класса, который хранит обьекты встроенных типов, не стоит хранить указатели, таким образом усложняя код и повышая риск ошибки. Его можно написать так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Dot {
    float a1, a2;
public:
    Dot(float k1 = 0.0, float k2 = 0.0)
        :a1(k1), a2(k2) {}
    void setData(const float k1, const float k2 = 0.0)
    {  a1 = k1; a2 = k2;  }
    float first() const { return a1; }
    float second() const { return a2; }
    //...
};    
int main()
{  
    // создать обьект с данными(координатами) и показать их
    Dot d(2.2, 3.3);
    cout << d.first() << ", " << d.second() << endl;
    // установить новые данные и показать их
    d.setData(3.45, 0.34);
    cout << d.first() << ", " << d.second() << endl;

    // typedef же позволяет получать новые имена типов
    typedef std::pair<float, float> dot;
    // после этого dot можно использовать как стандартную  пару
    // проделать то же самое не  написав класс         
    dot xy(2.2, 3.3);
    cout << xy.first <<", " << xy.second << endl;
    xy = std::make_pair(3.45, 0.34);
    cout << xy.first << ", " <<xy.second;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы создали оператор равенства, который считывает из памяти два рядом расположенные объекта памяти типа **float**. Забыли методы расположить для внешнего использовании с помощью декларации **public:**.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

class dot
{
    float *a1, *a2;
public:    
    dot()
    {
        a1 = new float;
        a2 = new float;
    }
    void operator = (const float *znach)
    {
        *a1 = *znach;
        *a2 = *(znach + 1);
        cout << " a = " << *a1 << " b = " << *a2 << endl;
    }
    ~dot()
    {
        delete a1;
        delete a2;
    }
};

int main(){
float memory[]={1,2,3,4};
dot x;
x= memory;
dot y;
y = memory+2;
}
```

Так должно работать.

```
> g++ dot.cpp 
> ./a.out 
 a = 1 b = 2
 a = 3 b = 4
```

Для удобства нужно создать метод

```
void SetXY(float x,float y){
  *a1 = x;
  *a2 = y; }
```

тогда можно использовать так:

```
dot d;
float x=5;
float y=6;
d.SetXY(x,y);
```

Перегрузка это большая тема. Конструируете новый объект, который использует все переменные класса **dot**. В новом классе вы можете добавить переменные дополнительные, добавить/переделать методы. Только переделать методы в обязательном порядке конструктор, деструктор, оператор равенства. Почитайте сначала теорию, и попробуйте. Если что не выходит выкладываете сюда.